# AMENT versus COLCON Ignore files

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I was wondering if AMENT_IGNORE files are still being used. I saw there are still some of them in some packages, like RTI Connext
https://github.com/ros2/rmw_connext/blob/master/rmw_connext_dynamic_cpp/AMENT_IGNORE

Do AMENT_IGNORE still have a purpose since there is COLCON_IGNORE? Or is it something that has not been updated after the release?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299729/ament-versus-colcon-ignore-files/) by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 527 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
Since the current ROS 2 releases can be built with both - `colcol` as well as `ament_tools` - we kept the `AMENT_IGNORE` files for now.

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-08-06**:
Thanks, I did not get that ament_tools was still being used. I though colcon became the new build tool. I guess I misread the release notes :P

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
`colcon` is indeed the recommended build tool as of Bouncy. But users are still using Ardent and we didn't want to require them to change their workflow. Also in Bouncy we still released `ament_tools` for convenience. But future releases won't contain `ament_tools` anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Colcon always ignores folders containing `COLCON_IGNORE`. If `colcon-ros` is installed then it will also ignore folders [containing `CATKIN_IGNORE` or `AMENT_IGNORE`](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/blob/d938fcbe386f7efc9f0731b6ff20c885d72b476a/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py#L50-L53).

As far as I know `ament_tools` doesn't support `COLCON_IGNORE`, so using the `AMENT_IGNORE` marker file allows building with either `ament` or `colcon`.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2018-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-06**:
`catkin_pkg` (used by `ament_tools`) considers all three marker files too: see https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/pull/226